# Should Indexes be used on logs database?

Tags: sql-server, logging, indexing

We have a database where logs about customer activities are saving every second.

On the other hand, the dashboard site selects recent data from this database every second. So there are hundreds of `insert` and `select` queries executed every second.

Should I use indexes on the database to reduce `select` statement execution time?

Comment: This is based on your future requirements, like using as a dba (or just making query in dbms) that in this case **no need** or using a user of an application that shows some logs report that in this case you **need**.

Comment: As your requirement that I found you need `index`es with a optimization by dba experts. you can ask your question in [DBA StackEschange](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid indexes.

If you are logging in real time, every user action that gets logged requires an insert statement. Indexes will slow down the inserts substantially from O(1) to O(log n) where log n is the size of the table. If your application is synchronous and single threaded... This will be bad.

I would ask myself these questions:

Do I need real time dashboards.

If so can I make logging occur on a separate thread or separate server so the slow insert speed isn't an issue?

Comment: we need real time dashboard as a monitoring tool to find customers which are experiencing problems in real time

Comment: Another option would be to periodically dump the log table to another location. The real time dashboard presumably only needs a small subset of the log data (current users). Depending on the scale of your site, that could be a very small table, small enough that the overhead of adding an index might not slow the site to a crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Without indexes your selects are going to become slower and slower over time as more data needs to be scanned. This is going to be unacceptable. Eventually you'll be forced to index anyway.

Add indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. As a believer of having a clustered index on (almost) every table (whether every table should have a clustered index has become a religious debate for some people) I used to be in school of thought that every table should have a clustered index. But due to very difficult issues I have discovered that while very useful for selects it  can (will ?) slow down insertions so much that it will hurt the application.

You probably want to test, with, and without, a clustered index to see if this happens. I also have noticed that at a certain point (between 8 and 12 indexes on a table) insertions can really slow down so even if you decide to go with the indexes (which can be a fine idea) too many can slow down your app. Test, and monitor, your app carefully.

You can get the best of both worlds  (no indexes on the log table so its fast and a table with lots of indexes for reporting) by using CDC (change data capture) on the log table. This is a low impact way of copying all changes to another table which can have indexes up to kazoo for fast selects with very little impact on the log table.